# create this list [[2], [3], [4], [3], [4], [5], [4], [5], [6]] using Python List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to generate below output using List comprehension technique in Python

**Output:**

```
[[2], [3], [4], [3], [4], [5], [4], [5], [6]]
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 3):

try: `list = [[x+y] for x in range(2,5) for y in range(3)]`

**output:**

```
>>> list[[2], [3], [4], [3], [4], [5], [4], [5], [6]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much